# Cannot read property 'refs' of null react error react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React js  0.14.3, I'm trying to create a Side Menu component using react but I don't know why I have an "Cannot read property 'refs' of null" when I use the refs like in the react documentation :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html
Can you help me please ?

```
'use strict';

    import React from 'react';
    import BaseComponent from './../../BaseComponent.react';
    import Menu from './SidePanelMenu';
    import MenuItem from './SidePanelMenuItem';

    class SidePanel extends BaseComponent {
        showLeft() {
            this.refs.leftmenu.show();
        }


        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.showLeft}>Show Left Menu!</button>

                    <Menu ref="leftmenu" alignment="left">
                        <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default SidePanel;
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to bind context of `this`.

The line where you are binding your `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={this.showLeft}
```

Needs to be:

```
onClick={this.showLeft.bind(this)}
```

Otherwise when you're calling `showLeft` it can't access `this`.

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
<button onClick={this.showLeft}>Show Left Menu!</button>
```

To this:

```
<button onClick={::this.showLeft}>Show Left Menu!</button>`
```

Comment: `JSX Parser: Unexpected token :` is what I get if I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written in ES6. Unlike ES5, there is no auto binding in ES6.

So you have to explicitly bind the function to the component instance using `this.functionName.bind(this)`.

Like so:

`<button onClick={this.showLeft.bind(this)}>Show Left Menu!</button>`

Without binding, when you click on the button, the `this` on the button refers to the button itself and not the function. So JavaScript tries to find `refs` on the button element, which gives you that error.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a this issue. try

```js
showLeft = () => {
            this.refs.leftmenu.show();
        }
```

or

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.showLeft = this.showLeft.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind it like this to avoid eslint error of `No .bind() or Arrow Functions in JSX Props`:

```
class SidePanel extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showLeft = this.showLeft.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
        };
    }

    showLeft() {
        this.refs.leftmenu.show();
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.showLeft}>Show Left Menu!</button>

                <Menu ref="leftmenu" alignment="left">
                    <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot bind undefined